# The class behind ui:include JSF tag

Tags: java, jsf, implementation, uiinclude

How is the `ui:include` tag implemented? Where can I find its implementation(source code)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's implementation dependent.

In [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net), it's the [`com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.1.7/com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/ui/IncludeHandler.java/).
In [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org), it's the [`org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler`](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl/2.1.6/org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/tag/ui/IncludeHandler.java/).