# How to use the IncludeHandler inside my custom component?

Tags: java, jsf-2, include, facelets, custom-component

In question:
[The class behind ui:include JSF tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789373/the-class-behind-uiinclude-jsf-tag/10789414#10789414)
I found out that I need to use the IncludeHandler to use

```
<ui:include>
```

programmatically.
However, the constructor needs a "config"-parameter and I don't know how to set this up.
Please give an example that shows how to use the IncludeHandler for a simple include like

```
<ui:include src="include.xhtml" />
```

My jsf-component currently is built programmaticly but I want to include some parts written as ".xhtml". So at the end a web-designer simply has a component like

```
<fg:generator></fg:generator>
```

and some ".xhtml"-files to play around with the styling. If there's a better approach than the IncludeHandler (still needs to be in Java) let me know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your sole purpose is to use `<ui:include>` programmatically, then you should be using [`FaceletContext#includeFacelet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletContext.html#includeFacelet%28javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.String%29) instead. Assuming that you're inside your custom component:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) facesContext.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
faceletContext.includeFacelet(this, "include.xhtml"); // this is your current UIComponent.
```

Here's another kickoff example which demonstrates dynamic include by command button:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="include" action="#{bean.include}" />
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="include" />
```

with

```
public void include() throws IOException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) facesContext.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
    faceletContext.includeFacelet(facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent("foo"), "include.xhtml");
}
```

Comment: Well if I could I would vote 50times for that. Worked on first try. Thank you so much!

Comment: This helped me out... thanks! For those interested: to add some <ui:param> you can use the follow code before including it: `faceletContext.getVariableMapper().setVariable("delegate", FacesUtils.createValueExpression("#{someExpression}", Object.class));` where FacesUtils is a simple helper class.